# Python - images to video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I want to combine frames to a video for a face recognition software.

I've found this online, but it gives me the error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
pathIn= '/Users/myname/placeholder1/placeholder2/face_recognition/readyData/'
pathOut = '/Users/myname/placeholder1/placeholder2/face_recognition/video.avi'
fps = 0.5
frame_array = []
files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
#for sorting the file names properly
files.sort(key = lambda x: x[5:-4])
files.sort()
frame_array = []
files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
#for sorting the file names properly
files.sort(key = lambda x: x[5:-4])
for i in range(len(files)):
    filename=pathIn + files[i]
    #reading each files
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    
    #inserting the frames into an image array
    frame_array.append(img)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), fps, size)
for i in range(len(frame_array)):
    # writing to a image array
    out.write(frame_array[i])
out.release()
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you very much, but I don't think it does. The code from your answer is more for reading the image, but I need to read multiple images from a folder and "shape" them. As I said, it isn't my code. I found it at medium.com and don't get all of it.

Comment: Yes. The problem in your code (I'll call it that even if you didn't write it) is that `cv2.imread` returns `None`, which is why you get that error message in the next line.